# Save clicked tab and menu links level one and two in local storage

Tags: html, jquery, css

I have this menu with dropdown links and each link represents a unique tab content element. When each link is clicked, that tab should be visible. So far so good but I'm facing two problems:

1. When the parent link is clicked, meaning only the one with dropdown menu, I want the first child link's tab content to be visible. Right now when I click for example the "Custom Pages" link, no tab content is visible and I have to click again on the first dropdown link.
2. The id of the clicked link is saved in local storage but I have no idea how to get it and add the class active for both the link and the tab content element.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/costheme/0tgfdwk2/57/)

[image: local storage save clicked menu link]

HTML:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="ct-panel">
  <div class="panel-menu">
      <ul class="nav-tabs">
        <li class="active"><a href="#layout-tab" class="tab-link">Layout</a></li>

        <li class="has-menu"><a href="#board-page-tab" class="tab-link">Custom Pages<i class="fa fa-fw icon fa-chevron-down caret" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
          <ul class="dropdown">
            <li class="active"><a href="#board-page-tab" class="tab-menu-link">Board Page</a></li>  
            <li><a href="#login-page-tab" class="tab-menu-link" >Login Page</a></li>    
          </ul>
        </li>   
        <li class="has-menu"><a href="#header-tab" class="tab-link">Main Blocks<i class="fa fa-fw icon fa-chevron-down caret" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
          <ul class="dropdown">
            <li class="active"><a href="#header-tab" class="tab-menu-link">Header</a></li>  
            <li><a href="#sidebar-tab" class="tab-menu-link">Sidebar</a></li>   
            <li><a href="#footer-tab" class="tab-menu-link">Footer</a></li> 
          </ul>
        </li>                                           
        <li><a href="#social-tab" class="tab-link">Social Links</a></li>    
        <li><a href="#general-tab" class="tab-link" >General</a></li>       
      </ul>
  </div>   
  <div class="panel-content">
    <div class="tab-content active" id="layout-tab"> Layout Tab content goes here</div>  
    <div class="tab-content" id="board-page-tab"> Board Page Tab content goes here</div>  
    <div class="tab-content" id="login-page-tab"> Login Page Tab content goes here</div> 
    <div class="tab-content" id="header-tab"> Header Tab content goes here</div>  
    <div class="tab-content" id="sidebar-tab"> Sidebar Tab content goes here</div>
    <div class="tab-content" id="footer-tab"> Footer Tab content goes here</div>  
    <div class="tab-content" id="social-tab"> Social Tab content goes here</div>  
    <div class="tab-content" id="general-tab"> General Tab content goes here</div> 
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.ct-panel {   
    display: flex;
}
.panel-menu {
    width: 300px;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
    flex-direction: column;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #181a1e;
}
.panel-content {
    margin-top: 50px;
    padding: 0 50px;
    width: 100%;
}
ul {
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
}
ul li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 500;
}
ul.nav-tabs > li.active, ul.nav-tabs > li:hover {
    background: #5b4dfb;
}
ul.nav-tabs > li > a {
    padding-left: 50px;
    position: relative;
}
ul.nav-tabs li a .caret {
    position: absolute;
    top: 17px;
    right: 20px;
    font-size: 12px;
}
ul.nav-tabs li a {
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 14px 20px;
    padding-left: 50px;
    display: block;
}
ul.nav-tabs li.active > a {
    color: #000000;
}
ul.nav-tabs li .dropdown {
    display: none;
}

ul.nav-tabs li.active .dropdown {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
ul.nav-tabs li.active .dropdown li a{
    padding-left: 70px;
}

.tab-content{
  display: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}
.tab-content.active{
  display: block;
}
.nav-tabs{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    // Level 1 links
    $('.nav-tabs > li').click(function (event) {        
        // add/remove current tab class to active
    $('.nav-tabs > li').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');     
    var parentAttrValue = $(this).not(".has-menu").find(".tab-link").attr('href');    
    
        // Show/Hide Tab Content
        $('.tab-content' + parentAttrValue).show().siblings().hide(); 
    
    //local storage    
    localStorage.setItem('selectedLevel1', parentAttrValue);    
    
    if(localStorage.getItem('selectedLevel1') == parentAttrValue ) {
        //add class with completed token
        $(this).addClass('active'); 
        $('.tab-content' + parentAttrValue).show().siblings().hide();
    }
    
        event.preventDefault(); 
    });
  
  // Level 2 links
    $('.nav-tabs > li.has-menu .dropdown li').click(function (event) {      
        // add/remove current tab class to active
    $('.nav-tabs > li.has-menu .dropdown li').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active'); 
    
    var childAttrValue = $(this).find(".tab-menu-link").attr('href'); 
        // Show/Hide Tabs
        $('.tab-content' + childAttrValue).show().siblings().hide(); 
    
    //local storage    
    localStorage.setItem('selectedLevel2', childAttrValue);    
    
    if(localStorage.getItem('selectedLevel2') == childAttrValue ) {
        //add class with completed token
        $(this).addClass('active'); 
        $('.tab-content' + childAttrValue).show().siblings().hide();
    }
        event.preventDefault(); 
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would make it simplified this way, hope it has sense to you:

```js
var navTabLinks = $('.nav-tabs a');
var firstHref = navTabLinks.first().attr('href');
var tabContents = $('.tab-content');
setActiveLinks = function( href ) {
    navTabLinks.filter(':not([href="'+href+'"])').removeClass('active');
    navTabLinks.filter('[href="'+href+'"]').addClass('active').closest('.dropdown').siblings('a').addClass('active');
    tabContents.filter(':not([id="'+href.substring(1)+'"])').removeClass('active');
    tabContents.filter('[id="'+href.substring(1)+'"]').addClass('active');
    setStorageHref( href );
};
navTabLinks.on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var thisLink = $(this);
    var thisHref = thisLink.attr('href');
    setActiveLinks( thisHref );
});
setStorageHref = function( href ) {
    localStorage.setItem('selectedHref', href);
};
getStorageHref = function() {
    return localStorage.getItem('selectedHref') || firstHref;
};
setActiveLinks( getStorageHref() );
```

```css
.ct-panel {
  display: flex;
}

.panel-menu {
  width: 300px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #181a1e;
}

.panel-content {
  margin-top: 50px;
  padding: 0 50px;
  width: 100%;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
}

ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
}

ul.nav-tabs li a.active,
ul.nav-tabs li a:hover {
  background: #5b4dfb;
}

ul.nav-tabs>li>a {
  padding-left: 50px;
  position: relative;
}

ul.nav-tabs li a .caret {
  position: absolute;
  top: 17px;
  right: 20px;
  font-size: 12px;
}

ul.nav-tabs li a {
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  padding-left: 50px;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul.nav-tabs li a.active {
  color: #000000;
}

ul.nav-tabs li .dropdown {
  display: none;
}

ul.nav-tabs li a.active + .dropdown {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

ul.nav-tabs li a.active + .dropdown li a {
  padding-left: 70px;
}

.tab-content {
  display: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

.tab-content.active {
  display: block;
}

.nav-tabs {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="ct-panel">
  <div class="panel-menu">
    <ul class="nav-tabs">
      <li><a href="#layout-tab" class="tab-link">Layout</a></li>

      <li class="has-menu"><a href="#board-page-tab" class="tab-link">Custom Pages<i class="fa fa-fw icon fa-chevron-down caret" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
        <ul class="dropdown">
          <li><a href="#board-page-tab" class="tab-menu-link">Board Page</a></li>
          <li><a href="#login-page-tab" class="tab-menu-link">Login Page</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="has-menu"><a href="#header-tab" class="tab-link">Main Blocks<i class="fa fa-fw icon fa-chevron-down caret" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
        <ul class="dropdown">
          <li><a href="#header-tab" class="tab-menu-link">Header</a></li>
          <li><a href="#sidebar-tab" class="tab-menu-link">Sidebar</a></li>
          <li><a href="#footer-tab" class="tab-menu-link">Footer</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#social-tab" class="tab-link">Social Links</a></li>
      <li><a href="#general-tab" class="tab-link">General</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-content">
    <div class="tab-content" id="layout-tab"> Layout Tab content goes here</div>
    <div class="tab-content" id="board-page-tab"> Board Page Tab content goes here</div>
    <div class="tab-content" id="login-page-tab"> Login Page Tab content goes here</div>
    <div class="tab-content" id="header-tab"> Header Tab content goes here</div>
    <div class="tab-content" id="sidebar-tab"> Sidebar Tab content goes here</div>
    <div class="tab-content" id="footer-tab"> Footer Tab content goes here</div>
    <div class="tab-content" id="social-tab"> Social Tab content goes here</div>
    <div class="tab-content" id="general-tab"> General Tab content goes here</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You will notice couple of CSS changes, too, because we set the `active` class to anchors.
Also on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/skobaljic/1bcd6yom/).

Comment: Great. I will add background: #5b4dfb; for ul.nav-tabs li a.active + .dropdown and it will be exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot.